# how do I know if the case is true?

Tags: c, binary

Let say if we are given a byte of binary data, how can you know what that data represents?

Is it true that you cant really know what the data represents because you need to know whether the one byte of binary data is represented in base 2, if it unsigned, signed, etc.

or is it that you can know what it represents since binary is base 2?

Comment: Really depends on what you mean by "what that data represents". You can't look at a byte in isolation and go "I know this, it's part of a JPEG image".

Comment: Data is just data. You need to know what it's supposed to be to make sense of it.

Comment: Is the ASCII string "hi!" a different thing from the little-endian representation of the number 2189672? At what point does this stop being programming and become philosophy? _I don't even know any more..._

Comment: @Notlikethat lol, I appreciate your question. ASCII's something old by now. Multibyte representation is common nowadays as we need to represent the richness of human languages all over the planet. Philosophy is the right word to use when doing programing, as every minute choices we do while writing code shapes our product. Depending on the choices, it leads us to success or failure, hence the importance of such resources as Stack overflow :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to tell that a byte of data has nothing to do with it's supposed representation.
You state that because it's a byte, it's a binary representation. this is purely assumption.
It depends on the intention of the guy who store the very data.
It might represent anything. As @nos told you, it really depend on the convention the setter used to store it.

You may have a complementary to 2 number, a signed byte on 7 bit, un unsigned on 8 bits, an octal representation (or a partial representation) or a mask (each group of byte within the byte may describer something totally different than another). It could also be a representation of a special coding. Etc.

This is truly unlimited.

In order to properly interpret it you need to know the underlying convention (a spec). @fede1024 told you about files, which use special character so that you can double check with the convention.

One more thing… Bear in mind that even binary data can be stored in natural order or in reverse order: that's endianness. So when you examine a number store in at least 2 bytes, you have to know whether the most significant byte is stored first or sec on din memory. If you misinterpret this, you won't understand the underlying piece of data. Endianness is a constant for a given processor.

Answer (score 1):

Base-2 and binary refer to the same thing. Typically, you do need to know whether the byte is signed or unsigned at least (in C). As for what the data represents - well, "it depends". Whether you want to interpret it as a single byte, as a character (or not), etc. With multi-byte data, you often also have to take endianness (ordering of the bytes into larger words) into account.

Answer (score 1):

Some files format start with a `magic number`, for example all PNG files starts with `89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A`. That said, if you have a general binary file without any kind of magic number, you can just guess about his contents.

You can try to open it with an hexadecimal editor, but there is no automatic way to understand what the data represents.

Answer (score 0):

You know it's base 2 since it's a byte of binary data, as you said. To see if it is true, in C everything but 0 is true. If it's 0, then it's false.

Comment: I was asking if we can know what it represent in decimal, if were per say given 10101100 without any other information..?

Comment: That's true because it's not 00000000.

Comment: @user2551612 Your title says "if the case is true". That's a confusing title, and one way to interpret it is as Ivan has answered here - but that's probably not what you're asking about.